# Preventing "Oh, I had flagged that already."

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I flag lots, but forget what I've flagged. When I reflag a post I had already flagged, I get told so by a helpful yellow box.

Surely it's bad usability to only say so afterward! It would really save me time if I could immediately see I've already flagged that post.

Comment: If the system had to check all flaggable content (answers, questions, and comments) every time you navigated to a new page, the number of interactions with the server would increase dramatically. I think this is probably going to be shot down for technical reasons.

Comment: What, one more database query would bring down a site that hands out hats to everyone for the holiday season? :)

Comment: Well, no... but you're just one of many, many users. It'd be one (or more) database query *per user*. Think about how many simultaneous users stackexchange has.

Comment: Think of it this way: you can see `edit` greyed out if a suggested edit is going, you can see how many views, you can even see the moment someone up/downvotes or comments/answers! I think just one tiny little box won't be too much.

Comment: @RavenDreamer maybe if it stored the fact in a temporary cookie it could handled client side, if there is any worry of spanking the database it's better than nothing I'd say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by the recent StackExchange-wide update to flagging and closing.

There is now a bracketed number next to the *flag* link if you've already raised flags on that post:

[image: the "already raised flags" number]

The flagging dialog box also does not show options to raise flags of the kinds you can't raise anymore:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Jeff [said (on MSO)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60019/146232):

> This would require many, many queries per page load per logged on users.

So: **No**.